# can't create an IoT hub on azure

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I have an azure 50 usd/month subscription. Want to create an IoT hub (The free tier) for this I get the error message: Only one Free IoT hub is allowed per subscription.

If I select the S1 standard tier, even though it is 25USD/month I get the following error message: Paid Iot Hub count would exceed allowed limit of 50 for the selected subscription.

My current credit is 50 usd, and I don't have any resource created.

How can I create an IoT hub in Azure in this circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug which affected the Azure portal for a few hours on Friday. Please try again, it should work now.

Apologies for the inconvenience.